# Create AWS SecretsManager using AWS CLI for Other type (plaintext)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to store a new Secret in AWS Secrets Manager using AWS CLI.

On console i get an option to create a **Other type of secrets** under **Select secret type** where i choose a plaintext type under **Specify the key/value pairs to be stored in this secret**.

I want to do that using CLI.
Below is the format to use the CLI Command

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret
--name <value>
[--client-request-token <value>]
[--description <value>]
[--kms-key-id <value>]
[--secret-binary <value>]
[--secret-string <value>]
[--tags <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Comment: For 'Other type of secret', just create the secret normally with the cli command you have there. You won't see a behavior change in the console.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--secret-string` option for this.

For Key-Value pairs you can do JSON formatted string and it will show up as Key-Value pairs in console:

`aws secretsmanager create-secret --name my-secret-kv-pairs --secret-string '{"foo":"bar"}'`

If you just want plain text you can do :

`aws secretsmanager create-secret --name my-secret-just-text --secret-string 'My random string'`

Comment: That option works for a single key/value pair, but if I try to do one with multiple key value pairs, then it creates them as a JSON object?  Is there another way to specify that multiple values are text and not JSON?

Comment: Nevermind I just figured it out.  it has to do with the way you do the "{ }"

This will yield the plaintext key/value pairs:
{
  "username": "alice",
  "password": "abc123xyz456",
  "accessToken": "myAccessToken1"
}

Whereas this will yield only the JSON variant of the secret Value:

{"username":"alice"},{"password":"abc123xyz456"},{"accessToken":"myAccessToken1"}